# How to make a required property if another property is empty and vice versa, in the JSON Schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

My current json schema definition is like this

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        },
        "input": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["name", "description", "type"]
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "type": "array",
            "maxItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 1
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["description", "type"]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["name", "description"]
}
```

So I need to validate the scheme for the following conditions:

1. If input array and output array are empty, both must be required;
2. If the input array is not empty, then the output array should not be required;
3. If the output array is not empty, then the input array should not be required;

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can provide you with a solution, but not right this moment. I expect people in other timezones will beat me, but if not, I'll be back! =]

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is the only one that we need to deal with. All properties are optional by default, so your conditions 2 and 3 translate to something like, "if the input array is not empty, then do nothing".

There are a couple of ways to achieve the first condition, but I suggest the following.

```
"allOf": {
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "input": { "const": [] },
      "output": { "const": [] }
    }
  },
  "then": { "required": ["input", "output"] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like all three of your requirements are self-fulfilling in json schema.

> If input array and output array are empty, both must be required

if `input` and `output` are empty arrays, they are already present, so saying they are required is redundant. sort of, "if x is present with the value [], then x must be present". Jason's schema correctly expresses the way you've phrased this, but I don't think there's any way for that schema to cause a validation error.

and Jason's answer is correct on points 2 and 3.

I'd suggest you think about some example instances you would expect to fail validation (and add them to your question here), and that will help to construct a schema that adds the proper constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, probably, I didn't express myself correctly. The schema should show error when:
1. `input` is pressent but contains 0 elements.